# Round cells then auto fill VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In cell AR8, I am looking for a macro that will insert this equation " =ROUND(IF(AP8>(AN8*P8),AP8,AN8*P8),2) " then auto fill it down the column for the next 800-1000 rows below.

Comment: did you try googling it? B/c i found it in less than 10 seconds....

Comment: try the recorder !

Comment: Send me the link Doug. I can't find one that works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306094/can-you-use-cells-instead-of-range-inside-of-an-autofill-function   If you cant figure out how to embed strings in cells before applying this than you should go learn the basics.

Comment: wait that link is exactly what you want. man you didnt even bother looking b/c it was THE FIRST RESULT from my google search :P

Comment: I'm looking to insert the equation into the macro as well. I am having trouble with the Round If function.

Comment: Which part of the ROUND-IF function are you struggling with?  Can you show the macro you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you get started.
[Range.Formula property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)
[Range.AutoFill method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx)

```
With Activesheet.Range("AR8")
    .Formula = "=ROUND(IF(AP8>(AN8*P8),AP8,AN8*P8),2)"
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(100), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```